# How to make Ubuntu stay online without a display?

Tags: networking, samba

So I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS as a home network, and currently it's just connected to my TV so I don't have to worry about burn in on my TV or getting another monitor that I'll just replace in 6 months due to the same thing.

Is there any way to keep the file sharing enabled without the display? As every time I turn off the display and go Idle for so long, my file sharing stops working and I can no longer access the drive I set up.

I am currently using Samba for my file sharing service.

Please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: If the computer is a desktop HP or Dell unit, then you may need to check the BIOS/UEFI settings to ensure the machine does not force the OS into Sleep when a display is not detected. This is a common “feature” to get around the age-old problem of people turning the display off before leaving work, but not turning the machine itself off.

Comment: The unit is a custom built rig. I double checked the ASRock BIOS for anything related to such and didn't see anything. The answer I received earlier has resolved the issue and I can now access my server at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the display has anything to do with this.  You just have to disable sleep and hibernation.

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target
```

Comment: Trying this now. I will let you know what comes of it, thank you!